# The pioneer anomaly

Tags: thermodynamics, history, space-travel

The RTG's powering the electronics had to reject hundreds of watts of black body radiation to space. The RTG’s reflected a portion of their radiation onto the backside of the main paraboidal antenna, much of this in the direction of travel of the spacecraft. Maxwellian electromagnetic radiation (EM) reaction is the mechanism that slowed the spacecraft. There is a tendency to refer to **"heat"** in almost all the literature on the subject.  I am unaware of any of the theory and practice of any mechanism of heat reaction, Maxwell's equations are never mentioned in any literature New physics, new dimensions, new physics and a revision of GR were proposed.  **"Anistropic heat reaction"** was proposed as early as 1998 on more than one occasion, but not taken seriously, too mundane and pedestrian or prosaic!  Papers were published, including calculations with good agreement with the observations.

Comment: Is there a particular answer you're looking for other than that engineering and experimental physics are complex and problems appear vastly simpler once they've been solved? Speaking from an experimental standpoint, I have spent a lot of time trying to understand problems whose ultimate resolution was far more obvious than an anisotropic distribution of waste heat.

Comment: How exactly could "years" have been saved by harnessing radiation reactions? The Pioneer spacecrafts had $\sim160~\rm W$ available at launch. Even if this was *all* radiated in one direction, that gives a tiny acceleration of $\sim 2\times 10^{-9}~\rm m/s^2$. This gives a change in speed of less than $1~\rm m/s$ over the time it took Pioneer to get to Saturn.

Comment: If you actually have a history question, it would probably be best asked on [History of Science and Mathematics SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com).

Comment: "The point that I'm trying to make here is that EM theory is not understood or appreciated by modern physicist's." $\leftarrow$ This suggests you aren't actually asking a question, but rather making a statement which falls under the category of "rant-in-disguise," which is specifically off-topic as mentioned [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).  As such, I'm voting to close.

Comment: Chris; I removed the exaggerated statement on the years  saved, I was doing a calculation on light sails on another forum and cut and pasted a bit in here. But the TRG's rejected a total 2.67kW.  72W of that provided the mysterious acceleration. The 160 W is probably referring  to the electrical power generated by the TRG's? I think the  thermocouples in the RTG's were only about 6% efficient

Comment: @Barry Yes, that's the electrical power, I didn't know the full power offhand. Still even with the full power, it would amount to a difference of a few meters per second in a spacecraft moving at kilometers per second, so the overall point stands. (Btw, you need to put an @ before someone's name if you want to notify them that you've replied).

Comment: As far as your edit to this post goes, this site is meant for Questions and Answers, not discussions. You shouldn't be trying to convince anyone of anything in your answer- just ask a question. Similarly in answers you should be *directly* answering the question. If you want to have discussions, you can bring it up in chat, or there are many fora on the internet that are more suited to discussion than this site.

Comment: @Chris  Where are these "many fora on the internet that are more suited to discussion than this site"

Comment: @Barry You can start with some of the suggestions on [this meta question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/391/106502). Obviously this isn't a complete listing of every forum on the internet, so it may involve some searching on your own. Regardless, this [isn't the forum you're looking for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92110/380389).

Comment: Have you read [Wikipedia’s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pioneer_anomaly#Explanation:_thermal_recoil_force) account of what caused the delay?

Comment: @G Smith  ....Yes, Is the account at odds with what I have said? Note reference No. 6 in Wiki. A cogent calculation of a thermal anistropic reaction as the solution in 1999, rejected!? Too prosaic maybe?

Answer (score 4):

Your question contains a false premise- that the pioneer anomaly was a simple, classical problem. Nothing about space vehicle dynamics is simple and over the decades-long duration of a deep space mission, a long list of tiny, almost imperceptible second- and third-order effects which ordinarily could be neglected become apparent.

It then becomes the task of the physics team supporting the project to propose mechanisms which could correctly account for the deviation despite the impossibility of observing the vehicle or its space environment directly due to their great distance from the earth.

There is nothing simple about that either.

Comment: "Your question contains a false premise- that the pioneer anomaly was a simple, classical problem."                
  I object to your comment, it is opinion based.  As far back as 1998 anistropic heat rejection was proposed, calculated in good agreement with observation and rejected.

Comment: A reference in support of my contention, because this site does not like PDf's , but prefers DOI's, as this article does not contain a DOI. I proffer a title only: ................................................................................................................................................A Prosaic Explanation for the Anomalous Accelerations Seen in Distant Spacecraft
Edward M. Murphy
The Johns Hopkins University
Dept. of Physics and Astronomy
3400 N. Charles Street
Baltimore, MD 21218
(September 21, 1998)